# Automate PDF verification

Tags: java, pdf, automation, verification

The company I work for wants to have the PDFs they are releasing to clients automatically reviewed, other than verifying some parts of the text, are there any good tools or opensource to allow you to be certain that a PDF that a client receives is what you expect it to be?
A lot of PDFs are generated dynamically so I don't have a clear baseline for exactly 1 for 1 how the files should look like.
I'm looking for solutions that grant me security in terms of sheet structure rather than text

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"allow you to be certain that a PDF that a client receives is what you expect it to be"*?

Answer (score 1):

using `iText` (in particular `pdf2Data`) you can extract all the information from a PDF file, and match it against a given template.

Going for this approach, you can easily verify whether a PDF contains all the information that you would expect to have in it.

Check out `pdf2Data` here:
http://pdf2data.online/

Comment: Yes, pdf2Data seems like a good fit to check whether the correct data is present in the correct places on the PDF.